# Transfer permissions on SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, permissions

How to transfer users and schema permissions on SQL Server 2012.

I tried with this:

- Right Click on Database of interest --> Tasks --> Generate Scripts.
- Then order of windows will change based on the version of SQL server.
- You can chose Users and Database roles in the 'Choose Objects' screen.
- In the 'Script Options' or related window look for 'Script Logins' and 'Script Object-Level Permissions'  and set them both to 'True'. Proceed through the wizard. When you generate the script you will get script to create logins, users, database roles and object level permissions  of the specific database.

but I wasn't successful.

Comment: How were you unsuccessful?  Did you receiver errors or did the generated script not perform as you expected?

Comment: Did you check the location where you saved the script? Or did you select "Save to Clipboard" option?